# How do I play mp4 and mkv on Parole media player?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, video

I have Xubuntu 22.04 LTS with Parole media player preinstalled. I am able to play audio formats and AVI video format without any problem, but when I try playing mp4 or mkv it doesn't display the video it's just a black screen, but you can hear the audio in the background. Is there some missing codecs I need to install to play it like gstreamer? In VLC I can play everything normally, but why does it not work on Parole?